# Remove label when image is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using HTML. I have added a label and image as below:

[image]

`on click` of `red cross mark` the corresponding label needs to be removed. How can I do this?

I have below the code but it is not working.

```
$("#lbRemove").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});



<section class="col2">        
        <div class="lbYourSelectedTarget">
            <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 100%;">Your selected businesses:</span>
            <div class="lbSelectedCriteriaTarget" style="border: 1px solid; height: 250px; overflow:scroll;">
                <ul class="lbCriteriaContainer">

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><a class="button right" href="index2.html">Continue</a>
      </section>



$(function(){
    $("select").multiselect();

    $("select").change(function () {    
        //console.log('asas: '+$(this).val());
        var str = $(this).val();
        /*var ff = "option1,option2";
        console.log(ff.split(",")[1]);      
        alert(str.length);*/
        if(str && str.length > 1){
            var last_element = str.pop();           
            $('.lbCriteriaContainer').append("<li id='"+ last_element +"' class='lbAlt'><a id='lbRemove' class='lbRemoveCriteria'><img src='images/cross.jpg' id='lbRemove' width='15' style='padding-top: 3px; cursor:hand ; cursor :pointer;' /></a><span> "+ last_element +"</span></li>");
            str = "";
        }else if (str && str.length == 1){
            $('.lbCriteriaContainer').append("<li id='"+ str +"' class='lbAlt'><a id='lbRemove' class='lbRemoveCriteria'><img src='images/cross.jpg' id='lbRemove' width='15' style='padding-top: 3px; cursor:hand ; cursor :pointer;' /></a><span> "+ str +"</span></li>");
            str = "";
        }
    }).change();

    $("#lbRemove").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please post the HTML code as well?

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle with your code.

Comment: can you please also show the HTML ? also I hope you are not using `#lbRemove` for all of those images

Comment: two elements with the same id are not valid. IDs are unique, if you wish to do something like that, use a class. Don't forget that elements can have multiple classes by using a space as a delimeter

Comment: updated the post with the code as well

Answer (score 7):

Seems that you use same `id` for multiple HTML elements.

Replace it with a class. So in HTML side you will have `class="lbRemove"` (instead of `id="lbRemove"`) and in jQuery:

```
$(".lbRemove").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Take a look at [**the difference between `id` and `class`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) in HTML:

- `id = name [CS]`

  > This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name **must be unique** in a document.
- `class = cdata-list [CS]`

  > This attribute assigns a class name or set of class names to an element. **Any number of elements may be assigned the same class** name or names. Multiple class names must be separated by white space characters.