# Remove all the <li> that its <a> tag starts with: 'ids'

Tags: jquery

I want to remove all the `<li>` containing a `<a>` element whose id starts with: 'ids'.

Before:

```
<li class="inner" style="width:100%;"><a style="width:100%;" id='ids1' href="#">hi</a></li>
<li class="inner" style="width:100%;"><a style="width:100%;" id='ids2' href="#">hello</a></li>
<li class="inner" style="width:100%;"><a style="width:100%;" id='ids2' href="#">hi</a></li>
<li class="inner" style="width:100%;"><a style="width:100%;" id='myid' href="#">hi</a></li>
```

After:

```
<li class="inner" style="width:100%;"><a style="width:100%;" id='myid' href="#">hi</a></li>
```

I tried:

```
$("a[id^='ids']").remove();
```

but what's about the `<li>` and the text?

Comment: Side note: be careful of duplicating the same `id` value on multiple tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
$("li").has("a[id^='ids']").remove();
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xehuj/1)

or

```
$("a[id^='ids']").parent().remove();
```

(supposing that `a` is a child of `li`)

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xehuj/)

Also, note that you [cannot have two elements with same id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17277703/1420197) (I refer to `ids2`).

Answer (score 6):

You may do

```
$("li").has("a[id^='ids']").remove();
```

or

```
$("a[id^='ids']").closest('li').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove the `li` and the text, you should probably traverse one level up before removing:

```
$("a[id^='ids']").parent().remove();
```